# What constitutes Halachic intercourse during Niddah?

Tags: marriage, niddah

Specifically when it comes to forbidden relationships during niddah and/or the following "clean" days, what constitutes an act of sexual intercourse punishable with Karet?

Presumably, a violation of the Harchakot would not constitute Halachic sexual intercourse, but where is the line between Harchakot and explicitly prohibited intercourse?

My understanding is that, with regard to other forbidden relationships, the Halachically enforceable definition of sexual intercourse extends to other forms of touching that fall under Derech Chiba, but again, regarding Niddah, would seemingly be a violation of the Harchakot rather than a punishable act of sex.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Shoel and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: This is nothing different from all other Arayos (forbidden relations). Only the penetration counts.

Comment: See Shut Mishne Sachir Even Haezer Siman 10 available here https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21273&st=&pgnum=30&hilite= about if beilah derech malbush mikrei beila or not.